# Virtual machine can't be reached via SNMP... Is it even possible?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, snmp, observium

I'm monitoring my work network via SNMP. Now, I have a virtual machine working as a DNS server so that I can access to them using hostnames (I'm using observium in another virtual machine, by the way).

It works like this: There's the physical machine, with two VM inside of it:

- Observium, monitoring my network
- DNS server

This is currently a demo, so in order to test the alerts settings I'm gonna kill the dns server, and see if observium is showing any alerts of it; but even though I disabled the firewall, and set the snmp settings in the dns, whenever I try to add the device to monitor, it shows the same message:

```
Trying v2c community <MyCommunity>
...
Could not reach <MyMachine> with given snmp community using v2c
```

At first I thought it would be because the setting were wrong, or something like that, but after checking so many tutorials, FAQ's and the Observium SNMP guide, I started to suspect it could be because the Observium's virtual machine can't monitor another VM because they're in the same physical machine.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome. Thanks beforehand.

(PS. English is not my native, so excuse me if I'm not being clear enough)

Comment: can you reach other VM from DNS server VM? ping? how did you build vm network?

Comment: Yes, I can ping the VMs from one machine to another. I configured the Observium VM to add my dns server as the first dns server, like this:     `dns-servers 192.168.0.200 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

Comment: what vms, what OS, is snmp running?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 12.04, on a Virtual Box machine. SNMP is running, but I can't snmpwalk- it.

Comment: maybe iptables blocking 161, 162 ports? can you snmpwalk from localhost?